# System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.UnintentionalCodeFirstException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I am getting System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.UnintentionalCodeFirstException error after publishing the code to azure.

The code working fine locally even after connecting to azure SQL db connection. But once it got published this issue is coming

How do I resolve this

Comment: have you tried to connect azure database  your local ssms?

Comment: yes. it worked.

Comment: Does Azure connection String is working from your local host?

Comment: Yeah . wile connecting to sql server in azure from loacalhost it works. But after publish this error is coming

Comment: Have you enabled the azure service from portal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Solved by removing the connection string from the Azure[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2nss.png)

It was actually overriding the connection string in Web.Config

Answer (score 0):

Enable Allow access to azure Service i think this might be the issue[image]

[Introduction to Remote Debugging on Azure Web Sites](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/introduction-to-remote-debugging-on-azure-web-sites/)

Comment: Delete connection string and add edmx by connecting to azure database.if  Edmx is in different project then copy the connection string from app.config and paste it to the web.config.this has to work